# Remove single value from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, function, data-structures

I have a list of dictionaries as data input. I also have a function that I want to iterate and remove single dictionaries (i.e. remove Pippin) based on the 'type' key so that he is not counted as a potential option in further iterations looking for an 'Uncertified Installer'.

Is this possible? Code below.

List of dictionaries

```
employees=[
    {
        'name':'Pippin',
        'type':'Uncertified Installer',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    },
    {
        'name':'Merry',
        'type':'Handyperson',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    },
    {
        'name':'Sam',
        'type':'Handyperson',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    },
    {
        'name':'Frodo',
        'type':'Uncertified Installer',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    }
```

Function so far

```
def schedule(buildings, employees):

        for building in buildings:
            remaining_employee_list=employees.copy()
            
            if building == 'single':
                remaining_employee_list[:]=[d for d in employees if (d.get('type')!='Handyperson') and (d.get('type')!='Uncertified Installer')]
                buildings.remove('single')
                
                print(building, remaining_employee_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is likely the easiest and most idiomatic way of doing this:

```py
employees = [
    {
        "name": "Pippin",
        "type": "Uncertified Installer",
        "days_available": ["M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F"],
    },
    {
        "name": "Merry",
        "type": "Handyperson",
        "days_available": ["M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F"],
    },
]

certified_employees = [
    employee
    for employee in employees
    if employee.get("type") != "Uncertified Installer" # here one could add additional conditions (for example a check on the building object)
]
```

Comment: Very similar to [already answered by DarkKnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227863/5730279) - except `get()` defense. Plus bonus: Link to docs, meaningful variable names and broken-down expression - clean style ️

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
employees=[
    {
        'name':'Pippin',
        'type':'Uncertified Installer',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    },
    {
        'name':'Merry',
        'type':'Handyperson',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    },
    {
        'name':'Sam',
        'type':'Handyperson',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    },
    {
        'name':'Frodo',
        'type':'Uncertified Installer',
        'days_available':['M','Tu','W','Th','F']
    }]

UI = 'Uncertified Installer'
E = [d for d in employees if d.get('type', UI) != UI]
print(E)
```

Comment: This seems correct but slightly different from the original posted function: the author is using `d.get('type')` to avoid KeyError and still filter when 'type' is missing. Whether that is a good design choice is a valid, but separate question.

Comment: I feel like this is close, but it removes every instance of 'Uncertified Installer' instead of removing them one by one as it iterates through the list... Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @kcsquared Yeah, that is a fair critique - I realized a little while ago that this is probably not the best way to go about this, but got too curious/annoyed to not keep trying haha.

Comment: I guess a good follow up question would be, since I have the data stored in a list of dictionaries, is it better practice to pull the data from the list of dictionaries into intermediate lists? I.e. recreate the data in a different structure?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer gives you. The *employees* list is untouched whereas the helpfully named list *E* is completely separate